# $\phi$ reaches the norm if $|| \phi || = \text{max }_{x \in B_X}|\phi(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let X be a normalized space and $\phi \in X ^ *$. We say that $\phi$ reaches the norm if $|| \phi || = \text{max }_{x \in B_X}|\phi(x)|$.I'm trying to show that $\phi \in c_0^* = \ell _1$ reaches the norm if only if $\phi \in c_{00}$. I'm trying to use canonical isometry for this:

$T:\ell_1 \to c_0^*$ such that $T(y)$=$\gamma_y$ where $\gamma_y :c_0 \to \mathbb{K}$ such that $\gamma_y(x)= \sum x_n y_n$. I get lost whenever I try to write the $||\phi||$ as a norm of sequence in $\ell_1$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\|\phi\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, we can think of elements of $c_0^*$ as sequences in $\ell_1$. In particular, the functional $\phi$ can be expressed as a sequence $(\phi(e^n))_{n=1}^\infty$, where $e^n$ is the $n$th standard basis vector (i.e. $0$s everywhere, except a $1$ in the $n$th entry). So,
$$\|\phi\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\phi(e^n)|.$$
Suppose $\phi(x) = \|\phi\|$, with $\|x\| \le 1$, i.e. $|x_n| \le 1$ for all $n$. Note that,
$$x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n e^n.$$
(This is not as trivial as it looks; try proving it using the fact that $x_n \to 0$.) Hence, using the continuity of $\phi$,
$$\phi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \phi(e^n) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| \cdot|\phi(e^n)| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\phi(e^n)| = \|\phi\| = \phi(x).$$
Hence, we must have
$$x_n \phi(e^n) = |x_n| \cdot|\phi(e^n)| = |\phi(e^n)|$$
for all $n$. Note that, whenever $|\phi(e^n)| \neq 0$, this implies $|x_n| = 1$. But, $x_n \to 0$, so after finitely many terms $|x_n| < 1$. Thus $\phi(e^n) = 0$ after finitely many terms, i.e. $(\phi(e_n))_{n=1}^\infty = T(\phi) \in c_{00}$.

(I'll leave the converse to you.)